# If $G/H\cong 0$, then $G\cong H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of an abelian group $G$.

If $G/H\cong 0$, then is it true that $G\cong H$?

My attempt of proof:

Consider $\psi: H\to G$, where $\psi(h)=h$. Then, $\ker\psi=0$, hence $\psi$ is injective.

Suppose to the contrary $\psi$ is not surjective, then there exist $g\in G$ such that $g\notin H$. But then that would imply that $g+H\neq H$ which contradicts $G/H\cong 0$.

Is the proof correct?

Additional question: In general, if $M/N\cong 0$, is it always true that $M\cong N$, where $M$,$N$ could be rings/modules/algebras, etc?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even better:  $G=H$.

Comment: Answer to additional question: yes, since those all imply the isomorphism as abelian groups, for which you have already seen $M=N$ in other comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the canonical projection $p\colon G \rightarrow G/H$. We know that $\mathrm{ker}\, p = H$. But if the image $G/H = 0$, then the kernel has to be everything; i.e. $H = \mathrm{ker}\, p = G$.

The same approach works for rings, modules, etc. Usually the most efficient way to prove some fact about quotient objects will only involve the canonical projection and its universal property.

Answer (score 2):

If $[g]\in G/H$ then $g\sim 0\Rightarrow g-0=g\in H\Rightarrow G\subseteq H\Rightarrow G=H.$